# Choose Extension Lead

Tags: mains, safety, cables

I am trying to understand better the characteristics I need to look at when choosing an extension lead (i.e. an extension cord that plugs into a socket, and gives me multiple sockets on the other end).

I know it is best to avoid using these, but I have to as I do not have enough sockets.

I have budgeted for expensive extension leads, as I want it to be as safe as possible, so the issue is how to get the best possible.

- Is the only risk overheating?
- As far as I understand, the thicker the extension lead, the safer it is because it is less likely to over heat. Is there any downside in getting the largest found cable?
- Some have a fuse, is it useful?
- Can I use extension lead bought in a country where mains is 220 V, in a country where mains is 230 V?

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only risk overheating ?

Over heating is number one risk even incase of branded extension cord. Please make sure that there is sufficient air cooling for the cable. Problem is that when the cord is fully loaded with high current the heat generated needs good passive ventilation atleast. When the cord is coilable, the coils in the inner rings gets over heated and will be a chain reaction with higher temperature and increased resistance and higher dissipation as well to an extent of fire.

> As far as I understand, the thicker the extension lead, the safer it
>   is because it is less likely to over heat. Is there any downside in
>   getting the largest found cable?

Definitely a plus provided that the cable is really a very good conductive cable than a thin cable with a very thick plastic sleeve.

> Some have a fuse, is it useful ?

Fuses save lives. Yes.

> Can I use extension lead bought in a country where Volts are 220V, in
>   a country where Volts are 230V ?

Yes for sure.